# Redux-logger doesn't log anything on webpack2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging, redux, react-redux

I've met a problem with redux logger.
It's just do nothing. No errors no logs, nothing.
here is the source.

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import diffLogger from 'redux-diff-logger';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, logger);
import reducer from './reducers';
export default createStore(reducer, middleware);
```

this code doesn't log anything.
I've tried every option of declaration.
Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "signup-form",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-diff-logger": "0.0.9",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.1",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

I've tried it on webpack 1 and redux-logger 2. Worked perfectly with slightly different syntax.

```
import logger from 'redux-logger';
const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger());
```

Has anybody met the same issue?
Thanks.

Comment: I've been struggling with this in last 2 days and now I have found out that problem was the firebug. tried with firefox builtin inspect and everything is working perfect. if you are using firebug too... don't.